# Flutter - How to make curved type of custom bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIACB.png)

I want to make this type of bottom navigation bar, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can dock your `FloatingActionButton` using the `floatingActionButtonLocation` property of `Scaffold`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: const Center(child: const Text('asdfasdfasdf')),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
        floatingActionButton: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 55),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5),
          ),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            child: const Icon(Icons.star_purple500_sharp),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: (int i) {},
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          currentIndex: 0,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.headset_mic_rounded),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.headset_mic_rounded),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.headset_mic_rounded),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.headset_mic_rounded),
              label: '',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want movable icon, not fixed on end,,, move icon to the current selected index

Comment: You can just adjust the `margin` when the selected index changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [curved_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar) package in bottomNavigationBar.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am new next time i will try  better